# Why my dropdown is disappearing while getting over image

Tags: html, css

Why my dropdown is disappearing while getting over image. When it is overlapping the image behind it, it is disappearing?? I have gotten this error first time. plss plsss help me!I have gotten this error first time. plss plss help me! I have got these kinds of erroes earlier but not this error which I am not able to solve

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
   
  }
  
  .logo {
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      justify-content: left;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0%;
  }
  
  .menu-bar {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5%;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul li {
    padding: 10px 30px;  
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul li a {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: var(--color-white);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  
  .fas {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 150%;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul li:hover .dropdown-menu ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  .menu-bar ul li:hover .dropdown-menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    font: lighter;
    color:rgb(49, 94, 20);
  }
  
.dropdown-menu ul li:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(96, 216, 206, 0.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(95, 95, 214, 0.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
  background-color: rgb(104, 161, 207);
  cursor:pointer;
}

.img1{
  transform: translate(-150%,100%);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Algo Tech</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu-bar">
      <img src="Logo With Removed Bg.png" class="logo" alt="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Strategy <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Short Straddle with Divisor Based SL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Short Straddle with Trailing SL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">09:20 Straddle</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">09:20 Straddle (Shift SL to Cost)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">09:20 Straddle (Roll the Pending Leg)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Index Combo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Index Option Buying</a></li>
                </div>
        <li><a href="#">Amibroker AFL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <img src="home_bg1.png" class="img1" alt="">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing its z-index ? (hover state)

Comment: Oh Thank you very very much!!